# control a botton Tpanel autoit

Tags: automation, autoit

I can not control the buttons off a program with AutoIt.
I've tried everything and nothing.

The information of the buttons is the following:

> Control
>   Class:  TPanel
>   Instance:   70
>   ClassnameNN:    TPanel70
>   Name:
>   Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:TPanel; INSTANCE:70]
>   ID: 133120
>   Text:
>   Position:   0, 71
>   Size:   246, 92
>   ControlClick Coords:    226, 29
>   Style:  0x56000000
>   ExStyle:    0x00010000
>   Handle: 0x0000000000020800

another example:

> Control
>   Class:  TNavBitButton
>   Instance:   2
>   ClassnameNN:    TNavBitButton2
>   Name:
>   Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:TNavBitButton; INSTANCE:2]
>   ID: 395608
>   Text:   Aceptar
>   Position:   227, 142
>   Size:   75, 25
>   ControlClick Coords:    33, 15
>   Style:  0x54010000

Comment: Please add some code that you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this helping you ?

```
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("yourWindow") 
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:TPanel; INSTANCE:70]")
```

See that I put the array displayed by the field `Advanced (Class)` in 3rd parameter of `ControlClick`.